# Daf Shiur in Far Rockaway / 5T?

Tags: product-recommendation, adult-learning, daf-yomi, united-states

I'm looking for a good daf shiur in far rockaway / 5T say anywhere around from 6:30 to 8 AM.

What I want in a Shiur is a clear and concise maagid, FYI.

Comment: this question is off topic and should be closed.

Comment: @Bach Which close reason is applicable? I don’t see how this is any different than other [tag:product-recommendation] posts.

Comment: @Bach Things which are unrelated to Judaism. How is searching for a Torah learning program unrelated to Judaism?

Answer (score 4):

I highly reccomend Rav Aryeh Lebowitzs ,he is very clear and concise ,you can sample his shiurim online .

[image]

Comment: Since the asker sought classes in the Five Towns or Far Rockaway, perhaps you can include also where (and when) these are?

Answer (score 1):

One of the local Jewish papers, I think it's Five Towns Jewish Times, but it might be the Home, has a shaded box on one of its pages listing places and times of DY shiurm in Five Towns and Far Rockaway. The list is thorough, but, I don't doubt that there are others not listed.

If you commute to Manhattan, one of the trains has a shiur in the last car.